# Service code stops when application is stopped

Tags: java, android, service

I have an app that gets users messages from database and if there is a new message it pushes a notification i use a service for that.. The service works fine when the app is opened or in the foreground.. But when I close it it doesn't work.. It is not destroyed or stopped it's just doesn't work :S I don't know why.. This is my service code :

```
public class BGService extends Service {

ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
ArrayList<String> requests = new ArrayList<String>();
Timer timer = new Timer();
Timer timer2 = new Timer();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("Chat", "BGService Destroyed");
    timer.cancel();
    timer.purge();
    timer2.cancel();
    timer2.purge();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Log.d("Chat", "BGService Started");
    messages = (ArrayList<Message>) intent.getExtras().get("messages");
    requests = (ArrayList<String>) intent.getExtras().get("requests");
    Log.d("Button Clicked", "Messages: " + messages);

    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            Log.d("Service", "Running");
        }
    }, 2000, 2000);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your telling the service to stop in your code.  Because your using onBind() it appears that your not starting the service and instead binging to it.  If you bind to a service the service automatically ends when your activity ends.

If you want to keep your service running.

- Start the service to keep service running
- Bind to the service to have a service while app is running
- Set a notification so the service is in the foreground
- Change your manifest so the service runs in a separate process

Start the service so you can return startsticky in the onStartCommand() to tell the os you want this to stick on

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
```

Start Service.  Bind to the service only if you have a connection to communicate with the service back and forth with.  This is returned from onBind()

```
startService(new Intent(context, ServiceLocationRecorder.class));
    // bind to the service
    if (!mIsBound) {
        // Bind to the service
        bindService(new Intent(context,
                ServiceLocationRecorder.class), mConnection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mIsBound = true;
    }
```

Binding to the service is used to setup a binder handler that you can communicate to and from the service with.  Returning null in onBind() defeats the purpose of the onBind() event so you could skip this code.

```
/**
 * When binding to the service, we return an interface to our messenger for
 * sending messages to the service.
 */
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mMessenger.getBinder();
}
```

set the service to the foreground you do this and the os will be less likely to end your service to get memory for another app.

```
 //this is done inside the service
startForeground(R.id.action_record, getMyCustomNotification());
```

Run the service in its own process then GC will be able to collect your activity and keep the service running.

```
<service
        android:name="com.example.service"


        android:process=":myseparateprocess" >s -->
    </service>
```